# Fetching data from teradata using teradata bteq utility

Tags: unix, automation, teradata

I am using Teradata bteq utility to run teradata commands form unix server.

I am able to connect to teradata, but while fetching data it gives only 7 columns and a dot(.) at end of decimal field.
I am using query,
select * from databasename.tablename

output
column1(decimal)   column2 column3(decimal)
   74664.              S        67469.

Don't know why it giving dot(.)

Can anybody help??

Answer (score 2):

By default BTEQ returns data in REPORT format with a width of 75 characters (this is an ancient default probably based on mainframe terminals), when you EXPORT it's 254.

You can easily change that by submitting a **.SET WIDTH xxx;** 65531 being the maximum.

Regarding the DECIMALs, check the definition, they're probably DECIMAL(x,0) without fractional part and the default format for a DECIMAL always includes the period.

If you want to get rid of the period you have to change the format either permanently changing it on column level or for a query using:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD column1 FORMAT '-(i)9'
or
SELECT column1 (FORMAT '-(i)9')
```

Comment: One more thing, FORMAT '-(i)9' not working with select *, can you suggest for select *

Comment: A FORMAT is applied on individual column, a "SELECT *" will always use the format according to the column definition.